# Make a list of tags style using listview/gridview android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want to know, can we make list of item that not having same width and stand after each other, like tags in blog website

for example:
shoes, clothes, shock,
burger,

so the item goes next after previous one, but in different width. im trying listview it goes new line every item, if gridview, it consistent width not fill the need.

As I'm in beginner level of android programming, I want to know if we can achieve that?

Comment: Its not clear what are you saying

Comment: I want to achieve list of items to be look like "tags cloud" style like on typical blog website. can we do that using listview or gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for [link](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/)

Comment: Can we use it for textbased item? not image?

Comment: Yes. You can use it with anything